Rolling packed spheres
If spheres are optimally packed in n-dimensional space, and one of them rolls, is it possible to compute how the remainder of the spheres move?
I got the question on looking at split octonions and the problem of rolling a ball on another ball of 3 times the radius.
The answer is trivial in 2 dimensions. But in the case of the maximally packed 24 dimensions there are deep holes. Must this case be rigid with no rotations possible?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Even for $n = 2$ it's not possible to roll optinally packed circles of the same size without slipping (the notion of rolling most relevant to the split octonion picture). Just think about $3$ mutually adjacent circles and what happens to the other circles when you try to rotate a single circle

This comes from orientation. Under what packings is it possible to roll the sphere?
